# Add a number of portfolio items with a click on button more in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, load, portfolio

I have a code in wordpress that gets me the first 8 portfolio images that I give in the backend. There should be a limit of 20 portfolio-items and I want a button load more, every time I click the button, 4 more portfolio items need to be loaded. New items should be loaded with ajax, anyone any idea?

```
<?php
                $posts = get_posts(array(
                    'numberposts' => 8,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_type' => 'cases',
                    'hierarchial' => true,
                    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                ));


                $key = 0;

                if($posts){
                    foreach($posts as $post){
                        echo '<div class="portfolio-item-'.$key.'" data-nonce="'. $nonce .'">';
                            echo '<a href="#" rel="'.get_the_ID().'" class="portfolio-link">';
                                echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'portfolio-size');
                            echo '</a>';
                        echo '</a></div>'; /*END PORTFOLIO-item*/

                        $key ++;
                    }

                    echo '<div class="buttonmore">Click me to see more work</div>';
                }


            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Infinite Scroll to accomplish the same thing on past projects. I would give that a try.

https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll

Comment: I can't get it to work :) I guess I'm not really able to figure out how it works correctly..

Comment: I had a bit of a tough time getting it to work on my site also. My issue was with my selectors. I suggest opening up a new issue on github with a link to your site. I was given an answer fairly quickly.  https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/issues